# Getting data from a running job in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am trying to create a job in Quartz.net that will monitor the state of all the other jobs and regularly update a log file. It only gets data back from a job once that job has completed execution, but I am trying to get on the fly information of the state of the job.

I wrote as simple a test job as possible and the test half works (which is frustrating because I can't tell what is different in the actual code). This is the test code:

**The jobs**

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
class SimpleFeedbackJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    private DateTime _lastRun;
    public string LastRun { get { return _lastRun.ToString(); } }
    private string _status;

    public void Interrupt()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _status = "working";
        _lastRun = DateTime.Now;

        JobDataMap jobData = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        jobData["time"] = LastRun;
        jobData["status"] = _status;

        DateTime n = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
        while (DateTime.Now < n) { }
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);

        _status = "idle";
        jobData["status"] = _status;
    }
}

public class LogUpdaterJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    private IScheduler _scheduler = TaskManager.Scheduler; //This is the same scheduler that will call this task :/
    private string _filepath = Configs.BasePath + @"Logs\log.txt";

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Func<string, string> UpdatedLineData
           = name =>
           {
               JobKey jobKey = _scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains("test")).Where(k => k.Name == name).First();
               IJobDetail job = _scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
               ITrigger trigger = _scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey).First();

               string status = job.JobDataMap.Get("time") as string;
               string time = job.JobDataMap.Get("status") as string;

               return string.Format("{0,-25} {1,-25}", time, status);
           };

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.Add(UpdatedLineData("feedback_test"));
        File.WriteAllLines(_filepath, lines);
    }

    public void Interrupt()
    {
    }
}
```

**Relevant extracts from `TaskScheduler`**

```
private static IScheduler _scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
public static IScheduler Scheduler { get { return _scheduler; } }

public void Run()
{
    _scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail feedbackJob = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleFeedbackJob>()
                                       .WithIdentity("feedback_test", "test")
                                       .UsingJobData("time", "")
                                       .UsingJobData("status", "")
                                       .Build();

    ITrigger feedbackTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                             .WithIdentity("feedback_test", "test")
                                             .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                                                                       .RepeatForever())
                                             .Build();

    IJobDetail loggerJob = JobBuilder.Create<LogUpdaterJob>()
                                     .WithIdentity("LogUpdater", "Admin")
                                     .Build();

    ITrigger loggerTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                           .WithIdentity("LogUpdater", "Admin")
                                           .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                                                                     .RepeatForever())
                                           .Build();

    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(feedbackJob, feedbackTrigger);
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(loggerJob, loggerTrigger);
}
```

So this does output some data to `log.txt`, it gets the last run time correct but it only ever displays a status of `"idle"` where I think it should be `"working"` half the time. In otherwords I would like the job data to be written to and accessible while the job is still running.

Is it possible to get data back from the job midway through the jobs `Execute()` like this?

Comment: I'm new to Quartz.NET and so won't be able to answer directly, but... maybe you could approach the problem in a different way? Since it seems you want all of your jobs to elicit the same behavior (e.g. report on status/progress to a common log), would it work to have all of your jobs inherit from a base class that does this? Just an idea... [Wish I could've answered for the bounty ;-)]

Comment: @InteXX That is exactly what I have done in the interim (and it's unlikely that I'll change it again now even if I do get an answer here as time is pressing on this project) - but it means locking every time a job wants to write and I'm not convinced I've done it in a 100% thread safe manner. It also means that I have to wait for a job to run before I can get certain information from it. But either way, surely there must be a way to get on the fly data from your jobs in Quartz.net my specific problem aside...

Comment: To date I haven't met a project that _didn't_ have pressing time :) OK, best of luck. If I think of something I'll let you know.

Comment: Could this help? [CrystalQuartz](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz)

Comment: It might... but it might not. I couldn't see any docs really so I don't know what it's capable of as an API. But I'd rather just log to a text file within each job than try figure out another third party library. Thanks though.

Comment: Oh... I was thinking you might fillet the source and modify it to your needs. But it sounds like you need this thing out the door yesterday.

Comment: @InteXX I just need to move on. But I think it would be good to get a proper answer to this for future users. If no one answers before the bounty is up, I guess post the CrystalQuartz as an answer and grab the bounty but it would help if you could briefly show how it works as there aren't really docs

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I don't really deserve the bounty just for that. I've never used CrystalQuarz; I just happened to stumble on it and thought that you might be able to pull something out of it for what you're doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like job data changes are not available until the job has finished. So instead use a dedicated data structure for the purpose of monitoring the job status. In the following example I have exposed the status information using a simple public static property `StatusInfo` which is available to the logging job at any time.

One more minor change: I have replaced `WriteAllLines` with `AppendAllLines`.

```
class StatusInfo
{
    public DateTime LastRun;
    public string Status;
}

[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
class SimpleFeedbackJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    public static StatusInfo StatusInfo;

    static SimpleFeedbackJob()
    {
        SetStatus("idle");
    }

    public void Interrupt()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        SetStatus("working");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SetStatus("idle");
    }

    private static void SetStatus(string status)
    {
        StatusInfo = new StatusInfo
            {
                LastRun = DateTime.Now,
                Status = status
            };
    }
}

class LogUpdaterJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    private string _filepath = @"D:\Temp\Logs\log.txt";

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        var statusInfo = SimpleFeedbackJob.StatusInfo;
        lines.Add(String.Format("{0,-25} {1,-25}",
            statusInfo.LastRun,
            statusInfo.Status));
        File.AppendAllLines(_filepath, lines);
    }

    public void Interrupt()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it works. In which case what's the point of the JobDataMap at all?

Comment: Its primary purpose is to allow scheduling multiple instances of a job of the same type with a different set of arguments. It's even more handy, if you want to persist the jobs in the database. For example if your process does not run continuously or you're running a Quartz cluster. In such case Quartz will take care of serialization and database handling.

Comment: Wait hang on... will this still work if I have many jobs that inherit from `SimpleFeedbackJob`? Is there a way to make `StatusInfo` `static` on the child classes?

Comment: To handle multiple job types, I would use a collection of `StatusInfo` instances, preferably a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.100).aspx). `JobKey` can be used as the dictionary key. Together with the helper `SetStatus` method, I would put the collection in its own separate class. I would not use a static status property in every job type, if I had many of them.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no way to do this out of the box. Here is the bit of code that executes your job in Quartz.Net.

```
// Execute the job
try
{
    if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        log.Debug("Calling Execute on job " + jobDetail.Key);
    }
    job.Execute(jec);
    endTime = SystemTime.UtcNow();
}
catch (JobExecutionException jee)
{
    endTime = SystemTime.UtcNow();
    jobExEx = jee;
    log.Info(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Job {0} threw a JobExecutionException: ", jobDetail.Key), jobExEx);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    endTime = SystemTime.UtcNow();
    log.Error(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Job {0} threw an unhandled Exception: ", jobDetail.Key), e);
    SchedulerException se = new SchedulerException("Job threw an unhandled exception.", e);
    qs.NotifySchedulerListenersError(
    string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Job ({0} threw an exception.", jec.JobDetail.Key), se);
    jobExEx = new JobExecutionException(se, false);
}
```

You'll see that once the execute method is called, the job runs off and does its thing and only returns when the job has finished executing, so there's no way to receive updates. This is in the [JobRunShell.cs](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Core/JobRunShell.cs) file in case you're interested in looking at the full context.

You can use job listeners to be notified of when jobs start running, error out or finish. That won't give you in progress information though. If you wanted to track progress of your jobs you could:

1. Use something like the logging model, where you pass the job a reference to the logger and it logs its progress to it. Then your other job can read from this logger to find status. You'd have to make this logger globally available as the jobs run on separate threads and there are threading considerations to handle.
2. You can swap out the implementation of the JobRunShell for yours. The built in JobRunShell has a  reference to the job's execution context so it would be able to read the data map (maybe using a timer?) and then report back on status. You'll have to create your own [IJobRunShellFactory](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Core/IJobRunShellFactory.cs) for this. Here is the default jobRunShellFactory implementation.

Quartz.Net executes jobs on different threads so communicating with them while they're in progress comes with the same issues as trying to communicate to any other regular thread while it's in flight. So if you've ever tried to solve that problem then you know what you're up against.